# javascript object is getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to get user input and push the value to array. But the array just copies the last value entered to all previous values. Not sure where am I going wrong.

```
    var arrTest = [];
    var objTest = {};
    var inputName = prompt("Enter name");
    var inputValue = prompt("Enter value");

while (inputName.length > 0 && inputValue > 0) { 
    objTest.name = inputName;
    objTest.value = inputValue;
    arrTest.push(objTest);
    inputName = prompt("Enter name");
    inputValue = prompt("Enter value");
}

printDetails(arrTest);
}

function printDetails(arrN){
    var vOutput = ""
    for(var vIndex = 0; vIndex < arrN.length ; vIndex++){
    vOutput = vOutput +" Name: " + arrN[vIndex].name+ " Value :" + dogN[vIndex].value+ ";
    }
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=vOutput;
}
```

If is enter just 1 value test 1, the output is

> Name: test Value : 1

If is enter just 2 values test 1, best 2 the output is

> Name: best Value : 2
>   Name: best Value : 2

My expectation is the value should be :

> Name: test Value : 1
>   Name: best Value : 2

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define `var objTest = {};` inside the while loop and use `arrTest.push(objTest);`

Comment: You're only ever creating one object...

Comment: Also, `arrTest(objTest);`?? It's an array, this should be throwing an error.

Comment: I think he means `arrTest.push(objTest);`

Comment: yep that is correct. I mistyped it here. I have been using arrTest.push(objTest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use arrTest.push(objTest) instead.

Also, declare objTest inside the while loop.

Code will be as,

```js
var arrTest = [];
var inputName, inputValue;

for (let i=0; i<3; i++) { 

// Here should be the declaration
    var objTest = {};

// User input
    inputName = prompt("Enter name");
    inputValue = prompt("Enter value");

    objTest.name = inputName;
    objTest.value = inputValue;
    arrTest.push(objTest);
}

printDetails(arrTest);

function printDetails(arrN){
    let vOutput = "";
    for(let vIndex = 0; vIndex < arrN.length ; vIndex++){
        vOutput = vOutput +" Name: " + arrN[vIndex].name+ " Value :" + arrN[vIndex].value+ "\n";
    }
    console.log(vOutput);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the observed behaviour is that when you're calling `arrTest.push(objTest)` you're actually adding a reference to an object to the array not the object itself. When you then change the object and push it again, you're adding another reference to the same object which then only contains the updated value.

You can work around that by either not working with a variable at all like this:

```
while (inputName.length > 0 && inputValue > 0) {
    arrTest.push({ name: inputName, value: inputValue });
    inputName = prompt("Enter name");
    inputValue = prompt("Enter value");
}
```

You can define the object inside the loop so you don't work on the referenced object:

```
while (inputName.length > 0 && inputValue > 0) {
    const objTest = {}
    objTest.name = inputName;
    objTest.value = inputValue;
    arrTest.push(objTest);
    inputName = prompt("Enter name");
    inputValue = prompt("Enter value");
}
```

Using the new spread syntax you could even implement something like this where you can use a variable, define it outside of the loop but still not use references like so:

```
while (inputName.length > 0 && inputValue > 0) {
    objTest.name = inputName;
    objTest.value = inputValue;
    arrTest.push({ ...objTest });
    inputName = prompt("Enter name");
    inputValue = prompt("Enter value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the code a bit. Try this.

```js
var arrTest = [];
var objTest = {};
var inputName = prompt("Enter name");
var inputValue = prompt("Enter value");

while (inputName.length > 0 && inputValue.length > 0) { 
    var objTest = {};
    objTest.name = inputName;
    objTest.value = inputValue;
    arrTest.push(objTest);
    inputName = prompt("Enter name");
    inputValue = prompt("Enter value");
}

printDetails(arrTest);

function printDetails(arrN){
  console.log(arrN)
  /* do for loop */
}
```